# Hardcode superuser password into bash script

Tags: bash

I wrote this small script to help me reduce the hassle involved in starting and stopping the lampp server on my local machine:

```
#!/bin/sh
#script to make lampp start/stop easier

if [ $1 == "start" ] ; then
    sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start &
elif [ $1 == "stop" ] ; then
    sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
else
    echo 'Wrong parameter.'
fi
```

I'd now like to go a step ahead and hardcode the superuser password into it so that I don't have to type it every time. I tried something like `echo 'XXXX' | sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start &` but got the three-unsuccessful-attempts error.

How can this be done?

Comment: It might be easier to add this script to sudoers with the nopasswd option, so you could just call the script as `sudo myscript.sh`.

Comment: I'd need to find out more about it, but doesn't that mean all the scripts that ever get created will have to be added to sudoers? God, I'm so lazy! :D

Comment: lazyness is good. you will make effectively writen (DRY) scripts... read the manual, anyway...

Comment: Here's another alternative - SetUI bit: http://askubuntu.com/a/167885/99884

Comment: Add `/opt/lampp/lampp` to `/etc/sudoers`, not `myscript.sh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your username is "dotslash":

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "dotslash ALL = NOPASSWD: /opt/lampp/lampp" > /etc/sudoers.d/dotslash'
```

Then you can

```
alias lampp='sudo /opt/lampp/lampp'
lampp start
```